# GLM SPSS code to R

Tags: r, spss, glm

SPSS code:

```
#* MULTIVARIATE REGRESSION APPROACH USING STRATUM DUMMIES AS REGRESSORS |
split file separate by a1 a2.
glm n1 n2 d1 d2 by stratum
/method = sstype(3) /intercept = exclude /save = resid /criteria = alpha(.05)  /design = stratum.
```

How to rewrite this SPSS code to R code?

Comment: You can see `plyr` and `?ddply` something like `ddply(file,.c(a1,a2),function(dat) glm(n1 ~n2+d1+d2|startum,data=dat)`

Comment: That sstype(3) is going to give you trouble. The authors of R functions think "type-III" sums of squares was a rather bad idea. And you should say what you understand the "criteria=" parameter is doing. Is this supposed to be stepwise procedure?

Comment: Be careful here - if "glm" in SPSS refers to a "general" linear model and not a generalized linear model, then the equivalent function in R is `lm` - a linear model.   The `Anova` function from package `car` is one way to go if you are looking for type III SS.